# How do I make a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python

Modify the function that you wrote for the previous task so that it returns a dictionary of dictionaries, rather than a list of dictionaries.  The dictionary should look like this

```
{ 
   1: {'Product': 'Milk', 'Brand': 'Anchor', 'Cost': '4.90'},   
   2: {'Product': 'Bread', 'Brand': 'Vogel', 'Cost': '3.80'} 
}
```

This is my code.

```
def run():
    dic_keys = ['Product', 'Brand', 'Cost']
    products = {}

    is_quit = False
    while not is_quit:
    product = {}
    for key in dic_keys:
        name = input("Enter {}: ".format(key))
        if name == 'quit':
            return products

        product[key] = name
    products.append(product)  <<--- Do I need to append the product(dictionary) to the 
                                    products(dictionary outside while loop?

print(run())
```

Previously, the result should look like this:

```
[{'Product': 'Milk', 'Brand': 'Anchor', 'Cost': '4.90'},
 {'Product': 'Bread', 'Brand': 'Vogel', 'Cost': '3.80'}]
```

Now it should be like this:

```
{ 1: {'Product': 'Milk', 'Brand': 'Anchor', 'Cost': '4.90'},
  2: {'Product': 'Bread', 'Brand': 'Vogel', 'Cost': '3.80'} }
```

A dictionary of a dictionaries, not a dictionary of a lists.

Comment: what is your question exactly

Comment: Easiest way would be to use `collection.defaultdict` i.e. `dict_of_dicts = defaultdict(dict)`

Comment: you can convert list of dicts to dict of dicts try this `res = dict(enumerate(products, 1))`

Answer (score 0):

you can't append values to a dictionary. To assign values to a dictionary, you need to parse the key to your dict like this:

```
products = {}
product = {'Product': 'Milk', 'Brand': 'Anchor', 'Cost': 4.90\
products[1] = product
```

Now you can access the values from array product via products[1], because 1 is the key to the values.

My approach for your question would be something like this:

```
def run():
   dic_keys = ['Product', 'Brand', 'Cost']
   dic_id = 1
   products = {}
   is_quit = False

   while not is_quit:
      product = {}
      for key in dic_keys:
         val = input("Enter {}: ".format(key))
         if val == "quit":
            is_quit = True
            break
         product[key] = val

      if len(product) == 3:
         products[dic_id] = product
      dic_id += 1

   return products

print(run())
```